# iOS Swift 4 Extension Range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

How can return an Int from a range of numbers in Swift?

I want to return an Int from a range of two numbers. Ultimately my goal is to assign the returned Int value to an indexPath.row of a tableview in cellforpathatindex method. I have written the extension but when I print the return value which is in the example below is k, I am only getting the min value instead of the entire range of values.

```
   extension Range {
      func returnIndexValue(min: Int, max: Int) -> Int {
        var indexArray = [Int]()
        let range = (min..<max)

        for i in range {
        return i
    }
    for p in indexArray {
        return p
    }
        return max
    }
 }

   let range: Range<Int> = 1..<10

   var k = range.returnIndexValue(min: 6, max: 100)

   print(k)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. Your method returns an `Int` – how can that be *"the entire range of values"* ?

Comment: Same, it's not clear what do you want to achieve. Your function returns Int. And the first return i means that you will not go into the seconf cycle because it will return the first i of the "range".

Comment: @Martin R and @ DJ-GlockHow can I return an Int from a range of numbers. That is what i want to achieve

Comment: Your code does return an Int from the range.

Comment: Yes you are right. but when i print the return value. I am getting only the first value which is min, instead of all the values from min to max

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is very unclear. Be more specific please. Do you want to return a random Int value from a defined range, return a range, etc. ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the `yield` statement in Python or C#, so that subsequent calls return different values? – And what exactly do you need the numbers for? `indexPath.row` is *given* in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you don't assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your function terminates at the first `return` it hits which is when it returns `min` in the first loop.

**Edit**

Your comments show you still don't get the problem with your code. A `return` statement **exits the function**. If you have a `return` in a loop as you do, the loop and the function are exited, the first time you execute the `return`. There's no way to magically go back and continue executing the loop. You're done.

Do you want a sequence of all the numbers in the range? Because a `Range` of `Int` is already a sequence. So you can create an array of all the values in the range simply by doing this:

```
let arrayOfInts = Array(1 ..< 4) // [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Your `for ... in` statement already does what you need, just replace the `return` with whatever it is you want to do for each value. For example:

```
for i in range
{
    print(i)
}
```

prints all the numbers from `min` to `max - 1`

Comment: But how can I return each of this integers in the arrayOfInts. Thats what am trying to achieve

Comment: You have to iterate through them. You are already doing it with the range `for i in min ..< max { /* do something */ }`

Comment: Yes you are right. but when i print the return value. I am getting only the first value which is min, instead of all the values from min to max

Answer (score 0):

if you want to return all the range of int values in an array then you can do it like that :

```
func returnIndexValue(min: Int, max: Int) -> [Int] {
    return Array(min...max)
}
```

And you don't need to use an extension for that.